# Setting the initial value of a select with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having trouble getting a select to populate with the initial value of a property in an object.

I have a `Location` object that has a property which is a collection of `urls`.

```
{ id: 1, name: 'Location1', state: 'md', headline: 'headline1', urls: [{ id: 1, url: 'www.google.com', type: { id: 1, type: 'Public'} }]}
```

When the user selects a `Location` I'm trying to display `url.type.type` as the selected option in the list but it always shows the `optionsCaption`.

Please find the full example in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bflemi3/2HS5J/)

```
var seedData = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Location1', state: 'md', headline: 'headline1', urls: [{ id: 1, url: 'www.google.com', type: { id: 1, type: 'Public'} }]},
    { id: 2, name: 'Location2', state: 'va', headline: 'headline2', urls: [{ id: 1, url: 'www.bing.com', type: { id: 2, type: 'Private'} }]},
    { id: 3, name: 'Location3', state: 'md', headline: 'headline3', urls: [{ id: 1, url: 'www.yahoo.com', type: { id: 1, type: 'Public'} }]}
];

function UrlType(data) {
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.type = ko.observable(data.type);
}

function Url(data) {
    this.id = data.id;
    this.url = ko.observable(data.url);
    this.type = ko.observable(new UrlType(data.type));
}

function Location(data, types, names) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = data.id;
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name).extend({ maxLength: 10, unique: { collection: names, externalValue: true } });
    self.state = ko.observable(data.state).extend({ pattern: '^[A-Za-z]{2}$'});
    self.headline = ko.observable();
    self.urls = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.urls, function(item) {
        return new Url(item);
    }));  
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);

    //update the data at any time
    self.update = function(data) {
        self.name(data.name);
        self.state(data.state);
        self.headline(data.headline);
        debugger;
        self.urls(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.urls, function(item){
            return new Url(item);
        }));
    };

    //initialize with our initial data
    self.update(data);
};

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.types = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Public' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Private' }
    ];

    self.locations = ko.observableArray([]);   

    self.selectedLocation = ko.observable();
    self.selectedLocationForEditing = ko.observable();

    self.names = ko.computed(function(){
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.locations(), function(item) {
            return item.name();
        });
    });  

    self.edit = function(item) {
        self.selectedLocation(item);
        self.selectedLocationForEditing(new Location(ko.toJS(item), self.types, self.names()));
    };

    self.cancel = function() {
        self.selectedLocation(null);
        self.selectedLocationForEditing(null);
    };

    self.update = function(item) {
        var selected = self.selectedLocation(),
            updated = ko.toJS(self.selectedLocationForEditing()); //get a clean copy

        if(item.errors().length == 0) {
            selected.update(updated);
            self.cancel();
        }
        else
            alert("Error");        
    };

    self.locations(ko.utils.arrayMap(seedData, function(item) {
        return new Location(item, self.types);
    })); 
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/2HS5J/5/

I've introduced `optionsValue: 'id'` to pull just that property as the selected option, and reduced the seedData to only containing `type: 1` (a unique id, rather than a type object). This allows knockout to easily map the `type` to one of your `$root.types` (otherwise, you would have to do this yourself). Additionally you were using `optionsText: 'type'` when your `options` array contains objects with a `name` property, not a 'type' property -- this is why knockout couldn't populate the select with the options.